# Why can I see my Apache server on port 80, but not my Webrick server on port 3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, webrick

I'm running Apache on port 80 and Rails (Webrick) on port 3000.

Using `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:3000`, I can see both servers. However, using my local IP, I can still see the Apache serv, but not the Rails serv.

Running cURL, again, Apache returns 200, but Rails returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip> port 3000: Connection refused`

**Update**
I restarted the server using the `-b` IP binding option and my IP, but can no longer hit it from localhost:3000. Is there a way to bind to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `0.0.0.0` as your argument. That will bind to all interfaces.

If you want to make this permanent you can monkey patch some of Rails by adding the following to `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge(Host: '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
    end
  end
end
```

Just keep in mind that this will make it publicly available if you're on a shared network.